# Moving an entity at an angle?

Tags: java, lwjgl, trigonometry, angle

i've literally been searching half an hour for this question and i did'nt find what i've been looking for. This is my first lwjgl program. Most of the stuff here is temporary, im just getting used to LWGJL so i can eventually turn this into a game. I'm just getting some basic functions up and running.

So basically, i want my entity to move in the direction of it's angle.

This is my movement code:

```
public static void moveAtAngle(Entity entity) {
    float x = entity.getX();
    float y = entity.getY();
    float xv = entity.getXV();
    float yv = entity.getYV();
    float angle = entity.getAngle();

    x += xv * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle - 90));
    y += yv * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle - 90));

    entity.setXAndY(x, y);
}

public static void move(Entity entity, float vel, float anglevel) {
    entity.setXV(entity.getXV() * vel);
    entity.setX(entity.getX() + entity.getXV());
    entity.setYV(entity.getYV() * vel);
    entity.setY(entity.getY() + entity.getYV());
    entity.setAV(entity.getAV() * anglevel);
    entity.setAngle(entity.getAngle() + entity.getAV());
}
```

This is my main update code:

```
public static void update() {
    Graphics.move(Entity.sprite, 0.95F, 0.99F);

    Graphics.moveAtAngle(Entity.sprite);

    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)) {
        Entity.sprite.setAV(Entity.sprite.getAV() + 0.1F);
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)) {
        Entity.sprite.setAV(Entity.sprite.getAV() - 0.1F);
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) {
        Entity.sprite.setYV(Entity.sprite.getYV() - 1);
    }
    if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) {
        Entity.sprite.setYV(Entity.sprite.getYV() + 1);
    }
}

public static void updateGraphics() {
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(0, SLDisplay.getWidth(), SLDisplay.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        update();

        glPushMatrix();
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glLoadIdentity();
            Graphics.rotate(Entity.sprite);
            Graphics.drawTriangle(Entity.sprite.getX(), Entity.sprite.getY(), 150F, (byte) 150,  (byte) 200, (byte) 255, (byte) 0);
        glPopMatrix();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

    destroy(false);
}
```

And my rotate code just for good measures:

```
public static void rotate(Entity entity) {
    glTranslatef(entity.getX(), entity.getY(), 0);
    glRotatef(-entity.getAngle(), 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(-entity.getX(), -entity.getY(), 0);

    if (entity.getAngle() <= 0){
        entity.setAngle(entity.getAngle() + 360);
    } else if (entity.getAngle() >= 360) {
        entity.setAngle(entity.getAngle() - 360);
    }
}
```

Please ask if you want to see anything else.

Thanks!

Comment: That's deprecated OpenGL, avoid it.

Comment: That's a bit vague; what part of it is deprecated?

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL

Comment: How am i supposed to tell what's deprecated and what's not? There are no annotations in GL11. How am i supposed to make it not deprecated?

Comment: Oh I see now, I must use GL45 i think (latest opengl version). But I don't seem to find any guides on it. Should i use LWJGL 3 or 2 with GL45

Comment: I can't answer that because I am used to work with jogl, you should try to ask on the lwjgl forums. However you should follow first some opengl tutorials.

Comment: However I do have some [samples](https://github.com/elect86/helloTriangle) and [tutorials](https://github.com/elect86/modern-jogl-examples) if they may interest you

Comment: Thanks. By the way, what is wrong with GL11? For me it's simple, and i dont need vbo and vaos if im drawing points and about 16 triangles. Is there any benefit to me using modern gl for a game with points and very little traingles?

Comment: `GL11` doesn't mean automatically deprecated. You do need vbo (you may not need vao however). No matter what you are going to draw. There are huge benefits, but let me point you this [introduction](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/About%20this%20Book.html#d5e16) that explains very well why you should avoid deprecated OpenGL.

Comment: My graphics card only supports gl 4.4 and below, is that bad? are there any benefits between 4.4 and 4.5 if i wish to use opengl 4?

Comment: 4.4 is quite good, most of time you get access to features of higher core profiles through extensions.

Comment: What is the result at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

Firstly,
Your problem is that you are technically using two directions at once to move your object.
1. You have an angle
2. You have vx and vy which is technically a vector with a direction.

Here are two methods using either of them :

*Assuming 0 degrees is positive x*

**Keep angle**

If you want to keep your angle variable you would need to have a general speed variable and then do this for each time you update the x and y:

```
float radAngle = Math.toRadians(angle);
x += speed * cos(radAngle); 
y += speed * sin(radAngle);
```

**Keep velocities**

This method required only using the trig functions each time the velocities change but it also uses the expensive sqrt function with the trigonometry functions.
You would need to use vx and vy only.
For updates you only would need to do this:

```
x += vx;
y += vy;
```

And then for setting vx and vy:

```
public void setAngle(float angle){
     angle = Math.toRadians(angle);
     float speed = Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy); //magnitude of movement vector
     vx = speed * Math.cos(angle);
     vy = speed * Math.sin(angle);
}
```

The second problem is this code:

```
 glTranslatef(entity.getX(), entity.getY(), 0); 
 glRotatef(-entity.getAngle(), 0, 0, 1);    
 glTranslatef(-entity.getX(), -entity.getY(), 0);
```

You will only need to translate it by its x and y why values once as it's x and y values are calculated according to the angle already. (You also seem to be moving the object back to it's original position with the negative translate)

And most java and lwjgl methods will require radians not degrees, so you would need to put

```
Math.toRadians(angle);
```

Into glRotate (why a negative before your angle I do not know though)

Comment: @MX wb  Also on the subtopic of using newer methods of OpenGL, look at the ThinMatrix youtube channel, he teach all that stuff and also movement.

Comment: Yea I fully understand modern gl now thanks to ThinMatrix. I'm making my own game engine now. Im stuck on a jre error now.

Comment: @MXwb I'm glad, Good luck with that, if this answer answered your question though please Mark it as approved

Comment: I will approve it because I know it solves the problem, but I'm not going to be using that in quite a while, I've had 2 rewrites of my game, and now trying to make cameras and stuff, so I'm quite far off moving in directions. But thanks anyway! I will use it when i get to it.